# Plotting seperate boxplot for each variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, multiple-columns, boxplot

I searched a lot for how to do it and could not find anything relevant.

I am trying to plot a separate boxplot for each variable in my dataset inside a for-loop. I tried the following:

```
for (column in names(articles)){
  if(is.numeric(articles[, column])) {
    bwplot(~column ,data = articles,main= paste(column))
  }
}
```

However, it is not producing what I want. How can I approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get all the numeric columns of the dataframe, use `lapply` to loop over each and create a list of plots.

```
cols <- names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)]

list_diag <- lapply(cols, function(x) 
                    bwplot(reformulate(x), data = iris, main = x))
list_diag[[1]]
```

[image]

---

To do this in a `for` loop we can do :

```
list_diag <- vector("list", length(cols))
for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
  list_diag[[i]] <- bwplot(reformulate(cols[i]), data = iris, main = cols[i])
 }
```

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example to test this on. As you can see it works for me without any error on `iris` dataset.

Comment: Thank you it works now. How can I produce all the boxplots in a for loop?